# Ogg Vorbis file not listed in media player

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-music, media-files

I have an Ogg Vorbis file (.ogg), which was discovered by the fancy new music player on Android Kitkat and it played fine. However, now that it is no longer officially a "recently added" file, I cannot seem to access it in the music player. It does not appear under "Songs", which otherwise lists all files as far as I can see.

The .ogg file is in the same directory as my mp3 files, which it can see.
And it can definitely still play, the file is not damaged. I have my own app under development for recording, which uses the GUI-free bare-bones media recorder and player libraries provided with Android. And it can play it even though it wasn't intended to!

Has anybody got any ideas? Can I force a refresh of the media library somehow? Clearing data and cache under settings does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is because it is listed as an Unknown piece by an Unknown artist as the only piece in my library. The Ubuntu Rhythmbox program I used to make the ogg vorbis file did not tag automatically for this particular piece, while it did for others.

The solution is to tag the file with for instance the "Audio Tag Tool", then it is searchable in the Android Music Player.

Understandable, but not obvious to me, I think it would make sense if the player app would search by file names as a last resort if no other matches were found.